# How exactly are fundamental planes derived for topological surfaces?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, klein-bottle

I've seen a couple examples of these `Fundamental Polygons/Planes`, but I do not understand how they're *derived* or what they even *mean*.

I'm fairly new to the subject in general.

As an example, the `Klein Bottle` has the fundamental square where two parallel sides point in the same direction, and the two others in opposite directions. I've also seen a version where a circle is used instead. I don't really understand what I'm supposed to get from these representations.

Comment: Gluing diagrams for the Klein bottle, projective space, torus etc., give a simple way to visualize and reason about surfaces with tricky topology, see [Mathematical Cut-and-Paste](http://mathcircle.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/handouts/2018/topology_of_surfaces_2018_0.pdf). In particular, they show that they have locally flat metrics, their homotopy and homology groups can be computed using them, etc. Deriving them as [fundamental domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain) of group actions is more complicated, and can be put off until later.

Comment: @Conifold this is quite the nice read, thank you!